# How edit this code to display content of category? (Wordpress)

Tags: wordpress

Can anyone help me to edit this code?
I have 2 categories, which after click on it I would display all posts from this category.
Now I see in both categories content of category id 8.
My code from category.php

```
    <?php
$args = array( 'posts_per_page' => 5, 'category' => 8);

$myposts = get_posts( $args );
foreach ( $myposts as $post ) : setup_postdata( $post ); ?>
    <li class="ikonakategoriiwpisu">
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?><?php the_post_thumbnail( 'thumbnail' ); ?>  </a><?php the_excerpt(); ?>
    </li>
<?php endforeach; 
wp_reset_postdata();?>
```

Comment: above code displaying all contents or in both page same content?

Comment: in both pages is the same content, only from category id 8

Comment: your page url something like domain.com/category/category-name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if your page url  have category, then you can use like this

```
$category_id = get_query_var('cat');
$args = array( 'posts_per_page' => 5, 'category' =>$category_id );
```